# How to send an object to node server via ajax?

Tags: ajax, node.js, body-parser

I am tring to send an object to my node server:

```
cropData: { x: '0', y: '300', width: '5760', height: '3240' }
```

via ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/",
    data: {cropData:cropData},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Success!')
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        console.log('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
    }
});
```

then get that in my server.js file:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.cropData);
});
```

when I log that into console I get:
first:
 proper object   => { x: '0', y: '300', width: '5760', height: '3240' }
and second:
 nonsense result => undefined

Why is that happening? first the proper object, and then undefined!

My bodyParser:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

I really cannot understand. Please help me.

Comment: What does "nonsense result" mean?

Comment: I mean I get something that I cannot understand why and it really bothers me.